# innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2, real danger if not using AUTO_INCREMENT columns

Tags: mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I've got a MySQL RDS database that uses pure generated GUIDs for key columns. The current value of the innodb_autoinc_lock_mode is 1, and due to some performance bottlenecks we want to change it 2. However, [in MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-modes) it says that:

> If you are using statement-based replication, set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 0 or 1 and use the same value on the source and its replicas. Auto-increment values are not ensured to be the same on the replicas as on the source if you use innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2 (“interleaved”) or configurations where the source and replicas do not use the same lock mode.

Our replication mode is set to Mixed (default in RDS). So what I read here is telling me to keep innodb_autoinc_lock mode to 0 or 1. However the question is: Given that we are NOT using AUTO_INCREMENT columns, what would be the issue with setting innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 2 with regards to statement-based replication and binlog replay (for recovery) ?

Comment: If you need any additional information answered, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, if you're truly not using any auto-increment identity fields, then that isn't a concern and you should be ok to switch to innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2.

The warning is purely about the fact that auto-increment fields can't have 100% guarantee of staying in sync across replicas when interleaved is set because it allows multiple INSERT statements to occur at the same time so the order of INSERTs (and auto-generation of the IDs) can occur in different orders between replicas and the source.

[This article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/26/what-is-innodb_autoinc_lock_mode-and-why-should-i-care/) goes into pretty good derail about the different values for that setting and their recommendations on when to use interleaved mode for performance reasons.